# Problem with ubuntu Installtion

Tags: system-installation

I have tried twice to install Ubuntu 14.04 using a live DVD on my laptop HP Pavilion zv600. Twice after taking too much time for  installation it reaches a point where I get the following msg:

```
 ... source error ID 134107 was not found when attempting to remove it ...
```

I am stuck. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using a live usb

Answer (score 0):

The DVDs are slow and old type of media you should use USB flash stick to install ubuntu, in your case the error is because of some broken files in DVD due to some burning problmes . All you have to do is to burn ubuntu.iso image into your empty usb stick and that's it you can try ubuntu without installing and can also install ubuntu into your system 4 times faster than DVD drives. To Burn iso file in usb you will need a software named pendrivelinux , you can get more details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) or [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: DVDs are fine - and can also be faster - using a slow burnign speed if possible generally does the trick. More graphical guides are available for how to make a Live USB - e.g [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for windows, or [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) for Mac.

Comment: @Wilf -I have mentioned pendrivelinux in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not whether to boot from DVD or USB. Its about making sure that your installation media is not corrupted. Always check whether your bootable media free of errors. To do so, after you boot your Live media (DVD or USB), make sure to 'Check drive For errors' before proceeding with installation. The tests ensure that you don't actually have a corrupt bootable media via which you are trying to install your Ubuntu.